# PHP empty() siempre evalúa vacío incluso si los campos están llenos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentado validar un formulario con php y ajax, actualmente estoy evaluando si los campos están vacíos y, si es así, imprimo el mensaje 'X is required', para ello estoy usando la función empty(). El problema es que empty() siempre evalúa true aunque los campos del formulario estén llenos.

**PHP**

```php
$name = $number = '';
$nameErr = $numberErr = '';
$errors = [];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $errors['nameErr'] = 'Name is required';
  }else{
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
  }
  if(empty($_POST['number'])){
    $errors['numberErr'] = 'Number is required';
  }else{
    $number = test_input($_POST['number']);
  }
}

echo json_encode($errors);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

**JS**

```js
var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var statusMessageHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('status-field-message');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){  
  var phpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  phpRequest.open('POST', 'form.php');
  phpRequest.onload = function(){
    var errorMessages = JSON.parse(phpRequest.responseText);
    var errorVars = [];
    for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(errorMessages).length; i++) {
      var objValue = errorMessages[Object.keys(errorMessages)[i]];      
      errorVars.push(objValue)
    }  
  }

for(i = 0; i<statusMessageHTML.length; i++){
  statusMessageHTML[i].innerHTML = errorVars[i];
}
  phpRequest.send(new FormData(myForm));
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<form method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name*">
    <span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Your phone number*">
    <span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>      
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Un `var_dump($_POST['name']);` imprime algo? Quizá sea útil que coloques el código de tu formulario.

Comment: @A. Cedano Disculpa, soy nuevo en php y no entiendo como usar los var_dump. Lo estoy colocando luego del condicional y antes del 'echo json_encode($errors);' pero, al abrir el archivo .php desde mi servidor(local), me muestra un mensaje de error, le tome una captura https://imgur.com/a/ykDk5. Por otro lado, acabo de editar la pregunta con mi código html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás enviando una petición POST sin cuerpo.

```js
"use strict";

function submitForm(oFormElement) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
  xhr.open(oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
  xhr.send(new FormData(oFormElement));
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="form.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
  <label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name*">
<span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Your phone number*">
<span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Prueba a hacerlo de esta manera. En lugar de asociar un evento al botón de envío, asociamos directamente el evento "enviar" en el formulario, y lo pasamos a si mismo como parámetro.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Muriano Añadí el código 'new FormData' como mencionaste pero el problema persiste. Hice una pequeña edición en la pregunta añadiendo el html y un poco de js(las variable que uso).

Comment: ¿Has añadido un id al formulario `<form>` y has sustituido 'myForm' por ese valor?

Comment: Es explícitamente necesario usar un 'id' en este caso? como puedes ver en mi js(editado hace unos minutos) llamo a mi form así 'var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];' y luego en el send 'phpRequest.send(new FormData(myForm));'

Comment: Es necesario si usas el método `getElementById`, en tu caso, parece correcta la forma de acceder al elemento y por lo tanto, no es necesario un id, no obstante, `getElementById` es, en términos de rendimiento, mucho más eficiente que `getElementByTagName`, por lo tanto, es una buena idea usarla. Ahora necesitamos que incluyas este código (es solo un ejemplo) `error_log(print_r($_POST, true));` al inicio de tu script, luego cuéntanos qué se está volcando en el log de php ( ¿sabes acceder a él?)

Comment: Cando dices script, te refieres a js? o php? estoy colocándolo al inicio en mi php. En cuanto al log de php, yo entiendo que debo abrir el archivo .php desde mi servidor en el navegador, si es así, solo puedo ver esto "[]"

Comment: Me refiero al php. Es correcto. `[]` significa vacío... Por lo tanto, los valores del formulario no están llegando al script php. He modificado sustancialmente mi respuesta, prueba a hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y si funciona. Además, tu código hizo que me diera cuenta de algo, yo no lo mencione aquí porque quería ahorrar líneas de código, pensé que no era relevante pero veo que sí. Pasa que yo tengo un 'event.preventDefault();' que se ejecuta al 'clickear' submit, esto lo hice con el objetivo de tratar el envío y recibo de datos con ajax y evitar el comportamiento normal del formulario al ser enviado.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Muriano. Sin embargo, el resultado del php aparece en una nueva página, y la idea de usar ajax es evitar eso, en que podría estar fallando?

Comment: onsubmit="submitForm(this); return false;"

Comment: Ya veo, entonces junto al 'prevent default' es necesario incluir el 'return false' para trabajar con ajax, verdad? Muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo.